# Multiple webpages with common title and navigation bars

Tags: html, css

I'm making a small personal academic website, which has multiple pages with a common structure.

**Question:** Is there a way to not repeat the code for the header and the menu (or navigation bar) in each of the html files? It would be great if I could put the code for the header and menu in another file, e.g. `header.html` and write a statement such as `\input{header.html}` (using TeX syntax) to include the file into `index.html` and `publications.html`.

Below is an example of what the website looks like.

Contents of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Title</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>My Name</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <p>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                &nbsp&nbsp
                <a href="publications.html">Publications</a>
                &nbsp&nbsp
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <p>
                This is my academic webpage.
            </p>
            <p>
                I am a 15th year PhD student in Filmmaking at Mickey's Institute of Technology (MIT).
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Contents of `publications.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Title</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>My Name</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <p>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                &nbsp&nbsp
                <a href="publications.html">Publications</a>
                &nbsp&nbsp
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <ol>
                <li>Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs, 1937</li>
                <li>Pinocchio, 1940</li>
                <li>The Reluctant Dragon, 1941</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Contents of `stylesheet.css`:

```
    body {font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: light; color: #250517; /*gray*/}
    a:link {text-decoration: none; color: #003399; /*blue*/}
    a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #003399; /*blue*/}
    a:active {text-decoration: none; color: #003399; /*blue*/}
    a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #003399; /*blue*/}

    #header {
        width:800px;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:50px;
    }

    #content {
        width:730px;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
        height:410px;
    }

    #menu {
        width:800px;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align:center;
        margin-bottom:50px;
        clear:both;
    }
```

Comment: If you have a server-side language available to you, like PHP, you can use includes.

Comment: You can even use SSI, if it is supported :).

Comment: If you don't/can't use server-side code, then using frames is your best bet. Frames are deprecated however, what I mean is `iframe` to load your content. Rest static header/menu remains on main page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just HTML and/or CSS, no, you cannot do this, as this requirement is outside their specifications (read 'purpose').

There are two approaches that remain:

1. If you are using a server side language (e.g. PHP) you can leverage off the libraries syntax for including content from other files inline (`include()`) in [the case of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), or [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)
2. You can use javascript, or a library like jQuery to fetch the output (content) of other pages, and inject them into your page at a specified place. This can be done as easily as using jQuery's `load()` method [as seen here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same thing. Then, I created a new file for storing the html of the navigation bar.

I created a file navbar.html which had all my navigation bar code. Then, in your main html file where you want navigation bar, just include this file by using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation').load('navbar.html');
});
```

Then at the place where you want navigation bar, just add this line:

```
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php for do the same job --
like
`include "navbar.html;`

Answer (score -1):

The solution provided by @Abhinav is only partially correct. It will not successfully load in chrome because navbar.html is of type file:// and not http:// as the jQuery load function expects. Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navigation').load('navbar.html');
});
```

and reference in your base html file with similar div method as previously shown:

```
<div class="navigation"></div>
```